# Conditional count column in Pandas where separate strings match in multiple columns

Tags: python, string, pandas, conditional-statements

I am attempting to recreate this report I have in Excel:

```
Dealer  Net NetSold NetRatio Phone PhSold PhRatio WalkIn WInSold WInRatio
Ford    671   31     4.62%    127    21    16.54%   93    24    25.81%
Toyota  863   37     4.29%    125    39    31.20%   97    32    32.99%
Chevy   826   67     8.11%    160    41    25.63%  224   126    56.25%
Dodge  1006   55     5.47%    121    28    23.14%  242    87    35.95%
Kia     910   57     6.26%    123    36    29.27%  202    92    45.54%
VW     1029   84     8.16%    316    65    20.57%  329   148    44.98%
Lexus  1250   73     5.84%    137    36    26.28%  138    69    50.00%
Total  6555  404     6.16%   1109   266    23.99% 1325   578    43.62%
```

Out of a csv that looks like this:

```
Dealer LeadType LeadStatusType
Chevy  Internet  Active
Ford   Internet  Active
Ford   Internet  Sold
Toyota Internet  Active
VW     Walk-in   Sold
Kia    Internet  Active
Dodge  Internet  Active
```

There's more data in the csv than that, which will be used in other pages in this report, but I'm really only looking to solve the part that I'm stuck on now, as I want to learn as much as possible, and to make sure that I'm on an okay track to keep progressing down.

I was able to get close to where I think I need to be with the following:

```
lead_counts = df.groupby('Dealer')['Lead Type'].value_counts().unstack()
```

which of course gives pretty data summing up the leads by type. The issue is that I now need to insert calculated columns based on other fields. For example: For each dealer, count the number of leads that are both LeadType='Internet' AND LeadStatusType='Sold'.

I've honestly tried so many things that I'm not going to be able to remember them all.

```
def leads_by_type(x):
    for dealer in dealers:
        return len(df[(df['Dealer'] == dealer) &(df['Lead Type'] == 'Internet') & (df['Lead Status Type'] == 'Sold')])
```

Tried something like this where I can reliably get the data I'm looking for, but I can't really figure out to apply it to a column.

I've tried simply:

```
lead_counts['NetSold'] = len(df[(df['Dealer'] == dealer) &(df['Lead Type'] == 'Internet') & (df['Lead Status Type'] == 'Sold')])
```

Any advice for how to proceed, or am I going about this the wrong way already? This is all very doable in Excel, and I often get asked why I'm trying to replicate it in Python. The answer is just automation and learning.

I know some of the columns don't exactly match up in the table and code, this is just because I shortened some of them on the table to clean it up to post.